# How you execute multiple of random words for one script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

The goal here is to execute four random words while using the same script instead of having to repeat it.

So far the script takes in the word and states if the word had been successful(command) or failed(not a command). However, I had to repeat it to get it to work. If I use || or &&, they're still treated as one command/word.

The word I'm trying to insert is date, date blah, someoneexistingcommand

How can I do it in a much efficient way?

```
date

and then check the exit status:

if test $? ==0
then
  echo valid
else
  echo invalid
fi

date blah

and then check the exit status:

if test $? ==0
then
  echo valid
else
  echo invalid
fi

someexistingcommand
and then check the exit status:

if test $? ==0
then
  echo valid
else
  echo invalid
fi
```

Thanks

Comment: the if statement should be ```if (( $? == 0 )); then``` or ```if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then``` (pay attention to the spaces)

Comment: They're both the same thing, ```test  $?==0 ;``` is the same thing as ```(( $? == 0))```. but thank you for your help. I appreciate it

Comment: no, ```if test $? ==0``` will fail. (test: 0: unary operator expected). and test ```$?==0``` means string ```"0==0"``` or ```"1==0"``` which will always evaluate as true. ```(( ))``` is an arithmetic evaluation, ```-eq``` ...arithmetic binary operator, ```==``` ...equality evaluation (sting comparision). Example ```test +1 -eq 1``` or ```((+1 == 1))``` vs ```test +1 == 1``` or ```[[ +1 == 1 ]]``` will not give same result.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the `for` loop construct. From `help for` on bash 5.0.16:

```
for: for NAME [in WORDS ... ] ; do COMMANDS; done
    Execute commands for each member in a list.

    The `for' loop executes a sequence of commands for each member in a
    list of items.  If `in WORDS ...;' is not present, then `in "$@"' is
    assumed.  For each element in WORDS, NAME is set to that element, and
    the COMMANDS are executed.

    Exit Status:
    Returns the status of the last command executed.
```

Though it's unclear how you will supply the commands to the script, and I haven't the reputation to request clarification. Assuming that the commands will be hard coded in your script, the following would work:

One-line form:

```
for command in "date" "date blah" "someoneexistingcommand"; do if $command; then echo valid; else echo invalid; fi; done
```

Multi-line form:

```
for command in "date" "date blah" "someoneexistingcommand"; do
  if $command; then
    echo valid
  else
    echo invalid
  fi
done
```

To break this down:

Iterate through the list, temporarily assigning the current value to the variable named "command". Note that "command" could be any valid variable name.
The "list" is every word after "in" and before the command separator (in this case a semicolon, ';')

`for command in "date" "date blah" "someoneexistingcommand"; do`

The following will be executed for each value of `$command`.
Run the command and test its exit status at the same time. Using "$?" is redundant.

```
  if $command; then
    echo valid
  else
    echo invalid
  fi
```

We're done running commands. Leave the for-loop.

```
done
```

The following is roughly equivalent:

```
if date; then
  echo valid
else
  echo invalid
fi
if date blah; then
  echo valid
else
  echo invalid
fi
if someoneexistingcommand; then
  echo valid
else
  echo invalid
fi
```